# CAS 5.3 login screen modification with extra field

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am working on apereo CAS 5.3.x, and in my application Login operation expects 3 data elements - username, password and a group code.

I need to add group code combo box. this combo box will get data from the database and at the time of submission need to submit the selected data from combo box also.

I have tried the code from this URL https://apereo.github.io/2019/02/25/cas61-custom-login-fields/ also.
but it is not working.

can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the code from this URL https://apereo.github.io/2019/02/25/cas61-custom-login-fields/ also. but it is not working.

The reason it may not be working is that the document quite early on states the following:

> Our starting position is based on:
>   CAS 6.1.x

That doesn't seem like it would match your CAS version, which as you state is 5.3.x.

So for that article to work, you need to be on the appropriate CAS version, and then try it out.

PS When you do, avoid phrases such as "it's not working". "It doesn't work" doesn't work. Please clearly state the problem, the issue, attach logs, describe versions, changes made, etc. [This post](https://apereo.github.io/2018/09/05/effective-diagnostics/#share-pain-responsibly) might share a few points on how to troubleshoot and share results.